# Identify rebooking within 4 weeks of rebooking

Tags: mysql

For every booking on the table which is canceled. I need to check if the customer_id of the canceled booking appears with another booking within 12 weeks of the booking date.

If there exists another booking with the exact customer_id within 4 weeks after the booking date, then 1, else 0

Table 1

| customer_email hash | booking_date | appointment_status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b642b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4452 | 01-01-2022 | canceled |
| a642b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4453 | 02-01-2022 | completed |
| a842b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4454 | 02-01-2022 | completed |
| z642b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4457 | 10-01-2022 | canceled |
| b642b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4452 | 15-01-2022 | completed |
| z642b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4457 | 15-02-2022 | canceled |
| z642b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4457 | 17-02-2022 | completed |

Result

| customer_hash | is_rebooked | booking_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b642b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4452 | 1 | 01-01-2021 |
| a642b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4453 | N/a | 02-01-2022 |
| a842b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4454 | N/a | 02-01-2022 |
| z642b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4457 | 0 | 10-01-2022 |
| b642b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4452 | N/a | 15-01-2022 |
| z642b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4457 | 1 | 15-02-2022 |
| z642b4217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4457 | N/a | 17-02-2022 |

Since customers 1 and 4 have made a rebooking I will need to check the booking date of the next appointment is within 4 weeks if yes then 1 else 0.

Customer 2 and 3 have completed their booking therefore N/a

I would like to solve this in Mysql

Thank you

Comment: *I need to check if the customer_id* - you don't have a *customer_id* column.

Comment: customer_id doesn't exit. We have to check using the customer_email_hash

Comment: What was wrong with the answer to the same question 3 days ago?

Comment: I need to work with the customer _hash rather than the customer_id. With that query I get the following error 'The aggregate operation 'SUM' cannot take a 'Boolean' data type as an argument.'

Comment: Please publish the query you tried.

Comment: SELECT t1.customer_id, 
       t1.booking_date,
       CASE WHEN t1.appointment_status = 'completed'
            THEN 'N/a'
            ELSE COALESCE(SUM(t2.appointment_status = 'completed'), 0)
            END is_rebooked
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
                  AND t1.booking_date < t2.booking_date
                  AND t1.booking_date + INTERVAL 15 DAY >= t2.booking_date
GROUP BY t1.customer_id, t1.booking_date, t1.appointment_status

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you're looking for is a `not exists` correlation, such as:

```
select customer_email_hash, 
  case when appointment_status='completed' then 'N/A' else
    case when exists (
      select * from t t2 
        where t2.customer_email_hash=t.customer_email_hash 
          and t2.booking_date > t.booking_date
          and t2.booking_date < Date_add(t.booking_date, interval 4 week)
    ) then '1' else '0' end
  end Is_Rebooked,
  booking_date
from t;
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bad0b34dbc76aab3e90c29e78f899a7b)